# Rails - update a model "in the future"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We need to add a feature which allows a user to decide, before he make a change to a model, when will this change will take affect (e.g. from tomorrow at 19:43)

The problem we've is that our model has many dependencies with many validations and there is a chance that future changes will conflict one another :

1. Make change A to take place tomorrow (pass validation test)
2. Make change B now - this change might have cause change A to be invalid.

Is there a known solution/Gem for that issue?
What is the best approach to tackle this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.financeit.ca/developit/blog/2013/12/06/introducing-purgatory/

Recently saw this gem on /r/rails, let me know how it works if you try it out.

Comment: It looks interesting but is not sufficient for what i need. The validation issues can still occur and there is no way to set that a change will be "vanished" after some time

Comment: maybe you can just remove ability to update record if it has future changes, that will remove conflict

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate the web server and DB, and have one instance for today and one for tomorrow.
At midnight, override the "tomorrow" DB with "today" one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use State Machines. You can read on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) for a quick introduction. And there are many gems you can use: at [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines). Each of these has its pros and cons, but the standard behaviour is allow define states, events and transitions between events, also some of them provides callbacks, validations and conditions.

I've been using [simple_states](https://github.com/svenfuchs/simple_states) which work fine even with complex set of models updated simultaneously. It has few lines of code, and I think that this can help when things goes wrong.

It depends on your system business rules, but you can set a state on the point "1. Make change A to take place tomorrow (pass validation test)", as "frozen" perhaps, and then when came the point "2. Make change B now - this change might have cause change A to be invalid", validate if this change can be performed with that status.

Then when your system will changes, it will be easy to add new events, statuses, and transitions and keep the system aligned with the updated business rules.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a very old question. But since I implemented something similar, I am answering this:

This can be easily achieved using the Sidekiq gem (which works with Redis).
I've actually used this gem to solve similar situation.

The main prominent use of Sidekiq is to incorporate the Background Jobs in Rails apps. Along with that Sidekiq provides additional functionalities like delaying in a particular call on an ActiveRecord object.

This is how it's to be done:

```
User.delay_for(2.weeks).whatever
```

Checkout more options here:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use rollback functionality:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html

Lets say you already have Change A in the queue for tomorrow which passed validation.
And someone is making a Change B to same model, you can do:

1. open rollback transaction.
2. Save new Change B to model
3. Validate Change A that's waiting in the queue.
4. If validation on Change A fails, rollback transaction which will return all Changes B to unchanged state.
5. Notify user that is doing Change B that his change is conflicting Change A.

Simplified Meta code example would be:

```
Transient.transaction do
  model = get_transient_model
  model.change = change_B
  model.save

  model.change = QueueChanges.get_change_A
  if not model.valid?
    notification_system.notify_user_about_conflict!
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Conflict!"
  else
    # we are good to go!
  end
end
```